# Whould the function be garbage collected before evaluating?

Tags: apache-flex, flash, actionscript-3, actionscript

I have that function in the class:

```
private function fireItemCreated(data: ByteArray): void {
    setTimeout(function(): void {
        var event: ItemCreatedEvent = new ItemCreatedEvent(data);
        dispatchEvent(event);
    }, 1000);
}
```

This function called to dispatch item created event when image thumbnail created.

But it delays event on some time to prevent user interface freezes. And I'm guessing what could be happen if garbage collector executes after *fireItemCreated* function call but before timer event. Does the closure will be removed or it stays until it will be executed?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

**It can't happen.**

If the function is called then `setTimeout` is called. The function-object passed to `setTimeout` creates a *strong closure-binding* with the linked execution context and *all* `setTimeout` callback functions are protected (*strongly held*) by the host engine (imagine there is an invisible `var timeouts = []` you can't access). It wouldn't be fun if timers were magically swallowed up by the evil Grime Captain.

Good question and Happy coding.

The issue described *can* actually happen in some other languages and their implementations of Timers. See [.NET's Threading.Timer Class](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.threading.timer.aspx) and the notes.

Comment: Thanks for the awesome answer. It makes it clear now. I assume after timer event it will be wiped by GC?

Comment: @Andrey M Since it's a `setTimeout` (and not, say, `setInterval`) when the timer expires the callback will be invoked and *the host (AS) will remove the timer definition/callback from the internal queue*. This will (unless there is something like use `arguments.caller` or another reference) cause the callback function to be eligible for reclamation -- this will in turn make the closure-binding eligible for reclamation (e.g. no longer strongly-binds to `data`). The GC will, *at it's discretion*, collect objects which are eligible for reclamation (that is, can't be strongly reached from a root).

Comment: See [Garbage Collection (Reachability)](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Garbage_collection_%28computer_science%29#Reachability_of_an_object)